# Product URL keys reset when saving product

Tags: magento-1.7, product-urls, url-key

In our store, we are using custom product URL keys: {manufacturer}-{product-key}, so for example "lg-42lf580v".

Sometimes when I execute some code to update a few products from a script, the product URL key gets reset to the default value without the manufacturer in it, so: "42lf580v".

This only happens when I use the `save()` method on a product, for example:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'SKU');

if ($product) {                            
        // Update the price.
        $product->setSpecialPrice(200);

        // Set the stock to not allow backorders.
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
        $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
        $stockItem->setData('backorders', 0);
        $stockItem->save();

        $product->save();
    }
```

In this case, I only want to update the backorders value, but still the product URL key gets reset sometimes. Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: It might not directly answer your question, but any reason for you to run a product save? `$stockItem->save();` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes you are correct, my example is not sufficient, I extracted this from a script for easier explanation, I'll add some more code.

Comment: Makes more sense now :) What do you use to generate the URL Key? I guess there is some kind of observer on `product save`? If you could display that code too, it would probably help. I can only imagine it's trying to get the manufacturer but for some reason doesn't have enough info.

Comment: I'm assuming that you load up `$productData` here because not all of the attributes load when you use `loadByAttribute()` but you never actually use `$productData` Is your original script this way?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it doesn't happen you can save the URL key on each product save in your script

```
[...]
$product->setUrlKey($product->getUrlKey());
$product->setUrlKeyCreateRedirect(null);
[...]
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I do now, but that's a workaround.

Comment: After changing products name, product url key will not update, i mean url not reset, how can i bulk reset products url key based on products name changes, now i updated 1000 of products name, howc an i bulk reset products url key. Because